# react issue =Attempted import error: 'GoogleApiWrapper' is not exported from 'google-map-react'

Tags: reactjs

Attempted import error: 'GoogleApiWrapper' is not exported from 'google-map-react'.
i am getting this issue help me   I am trying to put google maps in my project

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot blind. Please provide the piece of code that's causing the error. I'm not familiar with this package, however it seems, based on the API (https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md), that there's indeed no such export.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a different package from this one google-map-react, the repo you're looking for is https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react.

google-map-react has no GoogleApiWrapper